# How do I get the index of a dt that is clicked with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML looks like:

```
<div id="aGroupOfLists">
    <dl id="list0">
        <dt> header0 </dt> 
        <dd> item0 in list0 </dd> 
        <dd> item1 in list0 </dd> 
        <dd> item2 in list0 </dd> 
    </dl>
    <dl id="list1">
        <dt> header1 </dt> 
        <dd> item0 in list1 </dd> 
        <dd> item1 in list1 </dd> 
    </dl>
</div>
```

Note that, I am putting two `dl`s in a `div`, and in each `dl` there are a few `dt`s.

I want to know which `dt` the user clicked on, by using jQuery.

So I wrote:

```
$('#list0').click(function() {
    var index = $("#list0").index(this);
    alert(index);
});
```

But it always gives the index `1`.

Thank you for answering.

Comment: You're binding the click handler to the DL, not the DTs.

Comment: My answer is the simplest....just accept it, you know you wanna..lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally suggest:

```
$('#aGroupOfLists').on('click', 'dl dt', function(e){
    // logs the index of the clicked 'dt' element amongst its siblings:
    console.log($(e.target).index());

    // logs the index of the clicked 'dt' from amongst all 'dt' elements:
    console.log($(e.target).index(e.target.tagName));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EDEeS/).

Based on the newly-added information in the question (and comments, below) from the OP, it's now clear we're trying to get the index of the `dd` elements, and the text therein, so:

```
$('#aGroupOfLists').on('click', 'dl dd', function(e){
    /* logs the index of the clicked 'dd' element amongst its siblings
       (which includes the 'dt' elements): */
    console.log($(e.target).index());

    // logs the index of the clicked 'dd' from amongst all 'dd' elements:
    console.log($(e.target).index(e.target.tagName));

    console.log('Text: ' + $el.text());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EDEeS/3/).

References:

- [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am working on it. But please, check out the question again. I made a mistake previously. The `dt` tag is actually for the header of the list. The items should be put in `dd` instead of `dt`. @David Thomas

Comment: So, you want to get the index of the `dt` or the `dd`?

Comment: I think I found the answer. Thank you for your hint. I will update my post soon.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

```
$('#list0 dt').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    alert(index);
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9GMg/)

Or if you want to access the indices for both `dl` nodes,

```
$('#aGroupOfLists dl dt').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    alert(index);
});
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9GMg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just...

```
$('dt').click(function(){
var index = $(this).index();
alert(index); // or just do whatever you want with index
}
```

Comment: Looks like OP wants to delegate the event handling to a single element to avoid creating maybe hundreds of event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('dl dt').click(function() {
    alert("DT Index: "+$(this).index());
});
```

**Fiddle** http://fiddle.jshell.net/4Crwj/

Answer (score -2):

If you want to click on the DT, you have to include that in the selector:

```
$('#list0 dt').click(function() {
    var index = $("#list0").index(this);
    alert(index);
});
```